# Connect to SQL Database 2008R2 via a subdomain

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-server

I actually have a remote database acess via TCP/IP

I've searched the web, but I only get results regarding remote SQL by IP.

So, is there a way to make my IP acessible from a sub-domain (e.q. bd.domain.com) ?

Thanks

Comment: that is nothing with your database, but simply adding the subdomain to your DNS (A record) and forward it to the "real" database ip

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, this is a DNS resolution issue, you need to make sure that your client can resolve the server.bd.domain.com name to the correct IP.  You need an A record in the bd domain's DNS in order for this to work properly.